# Validate Sudoku (N by N)

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem, random, sudoku

## Challenge :

Create a random (`pseudo random`) Sudoku board with dimension `n x n`

---

## Input :

Given :

- `n` where :

  2 < n < 100

---

## Output :

`true` / `false` depending on whether the board is valid or not.

---

## Examples :

For n = 3 :

```
[7, 8, 4, 1, 5, 9, 3, 2, 6], [5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 2, 8, 4, 1], [6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5, 9],

[9, 2, 8, 7, 1, 5, 4, 6, 3], [3, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6, 1, 9, 2], [4, 6, 1, 9, 2, 3, 5, 8, 7],

[8, 7, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5], [2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 1, 9, 7, 8], [1, 9, 5, 2, 8, 7, 6, 3, 4]
```

This is ^ the random generated board.

#### Output : `true`

---

## Note :

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes (for each programming language) wins.
- Given input `n` will always be an integer (non-decimal value) and between the two mentioned constrains

Comment: In my opinion, this is too close to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22443/31516), but I won't hammer it...

Comment: We're supposed to create a random board then decide whether it is valid? Maybe simply generating a random valid board would be a better challenge.

Comment: @StewiwGriffin I’ve read both challenges carefully and I think that the differences are insignificant, so I chose to hammer-close it as a dupe. If I would have had the option to VTC but not hammer, I would have done so.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder : I disagree with you

Comment: I think it's a duplicate, too. There is already a challenge for validating, so the only difference is that you need to generate a random 9x9 matrix. So basically the entire hard (challenge) part already exists elsewhere on the site.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Feel free to, this is solely my opinion.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman If you change the challenge to my suggestion above I think it would be reopened and it would be a good challenge

Comment: @dylnan Still not that different. Then it's just `do { x = random_board(); } while ( invalid_board(x) );`

Comment: @user202729 true. Maybe if you were asked to generate a valid board at size of the input that didn’t need to be random it wouldn’t be the same method